# Melhor solução para três tipos de usuários

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estou iniciando em *frameworks* MVC com Laravel 5.3

Tenho 3 tipos muito distintos de usuários, `OperadoresDoSistema`, `AnunciantesDoPortal` e `ClientesCompradores`, que podem visualizar o anúncio.
Cada um tem suas sessões, seus *dashboards*, telas de *login* e demais recursos isoladamente.

Lendo a documentação, encontro apenas uma geração de autenticação para um tipo simples de `User`.
Qual a melhor solução para criar autenticação para os 3 tipos?

- Modificar esta tabela Users, integrando-a com os 3 *roles*?
- Modificar o gerador do Laravel para este fim, criando 3 tabelas tipo
  *User*?
- Fazer minha própria autenticação manualmente, apoiada em *Guards* e
  *Auth*?

O melhor caminho é utilizar pacotes externos?

Isso é uma boa prática?

Já li [este post](https://youtu.be/VuUX3NHsGag), mas não me resolveu:

Já vi [este vídeo](https://youtu.be/VuUX3NHsGag) também, mas me pareceu subverter o Laravel:

Qual é a solução mais indicada?
**Qual o Laravel's way?**

Comment: Qual a versão ao certo do Laravel? O 5.2 já torna isso muito simples

Comment: @Miguel ele está usando a 5.3 eu acho

Comment: Costumo tratar na mão permissões de usuário, gosto de criar por nível de acesso de 1 a 3 por exemplo, e tratar as permissões, por exemplo um usuario com permissão 1 não consegue usar um metodo que precisa de permissao 2, mas isso é nível hierárquico e dependendo do que precisa, não vai servir bem pra você

Comment: Oi, @FelipePaetzold! De fato, permissionamento hierárquico não me serve para este caso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A partir do Laravel 5.2 que um sistema de multi autenticação foi tornado simples de se fazer (tenho quase a certeza que no 5.3 o sistema continua igual), neste caso temos dois tipos de utilizadores a autenticar (admin e cliente), mas pode ser escalável para mais:

config/auth.php:

```
...
'guards' => [ // acrescentar aqui mais tipos de utilizadores a autenticar
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admin',
    ],
    'client' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'client',
    ],
],

'providers' => [ // acrescentar aqui mais tipos de utilizadores e respetivos models a autenticar
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
    'client' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Client::class,
    ],
],
...
```

Controlador/metodo responsável pela autenticação do Admin neste caso, post do formulário de login:

```
public function admin_auth() {
    $credentials = array(request()->email, request()->password);
    if(!Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials, request()->has('remember_me'))) { // note que no guard estou a especificar um dos que defini em `config/auth`
        return redirect('/'); // autenticação não foi bem sucedida
    }
    return redirect('/admin/dashboard'); // se entrar foi bem sucedida
}
```

Depois na rota `/admin/dashboard`, e restantes rotas em que seja preciso estar autenticado, seja cliente ou admin:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function() {
    Route::get('/admin/dashboard', 'AdminController@home_dashboard'); // se entrar nesta rota é porque está autenticado e vamos para home do dashboard
}
```

Em que no middleware `RedirectIfAuthenticated` podemos ter:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null) {
    $guards = array('admin', 'client'); // colocar também aqui os tipos de utilizadores com rotas autenticadas, os guards definidos em config/auth.php
    $guard = $request->segments()[0]; // ajustar, neste caso o guard é o primeiro segmento do url, ex: http://exemplo.com/admin/... ou http://exemplo.com/client/..., em que o $guard vai ser admin ou client dependendo do que vem depois do ...com/
    if(in_array($guard, $guards)) {
        if(Auth::guard($guard)->check()) { // verificar se este tipo de utilizador, guard, está autenticado
            return $next($request); // bem sucedido executar o código definido na rota (controlador/metodo)
        }
    }
    return redirect('/'); // utilizador não autenticado, redirecionar
}
```