# Laravel 5.3 Multi Auth com Herança

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

Estou usando o Laravel 5.3 e me deparei com um problema. Preciso fazer uma autenticação de múltiplos tipos de usuários. Vi na documentação e em alguns tutoriais que é possível fazer isto no Laravel, o problema é que todos os que vi mostram como fazer uma autenticação quando cada tipo de usuário tem uma tabela distinta, ex: um tabela para admin, outra para usuario comum e etc. No meu banco de dados existe algumas tabelas como, coordenador, professor, aluno e outras que possuem uma foreignKey/primaryKey que referenciam à uma tabela chamada usuario. Tentei fazer algumas implementações que vi em alguns tutoriais como esse: 
[Melhor solução para três tipos de usuários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/161940/melhor-solu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-tr%C3%AAs-tipos-de-usu%C3%A1rios-no-laravel-5-3), mas não funcionou. Lembrando que existe apenas uma pagina de login para todos os usuários, pois após um usuário fazer o login que eu irei definir o que cada tipo de usuário vai poder ver ou fazer no sistema.

Se alguém puder me dar uma dica de como fazer a autenticação, eu agradeço bastante.

Comment: Veja se isto ajuda, mas acho que se refere ao guard (tipo de utilizador, tabela respetiva) que quer. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/161940/melhor-solução-para-três-tipos-de-usuários-no-laravel-5-3/161951#161951

Comment: é melhor usar a técnica de `roles` ou papel, um usuário pode ter vários papel, com essa informação, crie middleware especifico para proteção do seu aplicativo.

Comment: Exatamente @Miguel, este exemplo utiliza tabelas respectivas para cada tipo de usuário.

Comment: Resolvi fazer justamente o que o @Virgilio Novic citou, se isso der certo eu comunico.

Comment: ok, boa sorte, sendo assim também acho que é o melhor